# I'm new in VBA coding, I run this code and get compile error right before (vlookup) word

Tags: excel, vba

Please help me analyze this code and make correction cause I am stuck.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sale_Purchase")
Dim lr As Long
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A")) 
sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Product.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Type.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Qty.Value
sh.Range("E" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Rate.Value
sh.Range("F" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Rate.Value * Me.txt_Qty.Value
If Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Purchase" Then
   sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = "NA"
Else
   sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = (Me.txt_Rate.Value * Me.txt_Qty.Value) -
   Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, _
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("B:D", 3, 0)) * Me.txt_Qty.Value
End If
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line: `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("B:D", 3, 0)) * Me.txt_Qty.Value` ?

Comment: Probably, I could have messed up when attempting to calculate profit
But, my Product_Master sheet has Product-B, Sale price-C, Purchase price-D columns & Sale_Purchase sheet has Product-B, Type-C, Qty-D, Price-E, Amount-F & Profit-G columns

Comment: Can you show us an example sheet?

Answer (score 0):

The `3,0` should be outside the `Range()`,  e.g. `VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("B:D"), 3, 0)`

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim sh As Worksheet, shMaster As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sale_Purchase")
    Set shMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master")
    Dim purchasePrice, lr As Long, ar(6)

    lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    ar(0) = lr
    ar(1) = Me.cmb_Product.Value
    ar(2) = Me.cmb_Type.Value
    ar(3) = Me.txt_Qty.Value
    ar(4) = Me.Txt_Rate.Value

    If ar(1) = "" Or ar(3) = "" Or ar(4) = "" Then Exit Sub
    ar(5) = ar(3) * ar(4) ' qty * rate

    If LCase(ar(2)) = "purchase" Then
        ar(6) = "NA"
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        purchasePrice = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ar(1), shMaster.Range("B:D"), 3, 0)
        If IsEmpty(purchasePrice) Then
            MsgBox ar(1) & " not found on master", vbExclamation
        Else
           ' profit
            ar(6) = ar(5) - (ar(3) * purchasePrice)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Resize(1, 7) = ar

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sale_Purchase")
Dim lr As Long
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A")) 
sh.Range("A" & lr + 1).Value = lr
sh.Range("B" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Product.Value
sh.Range("C" & lr + 1).Value = Me.cmb_Type.Value
sh.Range("D" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Qty.Value
sh.Range("E" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Rate.Value
sh.Range("F" & lr + 1).Value = Me.txt_Rate.Value * Me.txt_Qty.Value
If Me.cmb_Type.Value = "Purchase" Then
sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = "NA"
Else

'Problem row disabled    
'sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = (Me.txt_Rate.Value * Me.txt_Qty.Value) -
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product,     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("B:D", 3, 0)) * Me.txt_Qty.Value

'changed to 
   sh.Range("G" & lr + 1).Value = (Me.txt_Rate.Value * Me.txt_Qty.Value) - Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.cmb_Product, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product_Master").Range("A:D"), 3) * Me.txt_qty.Value
End If
```